# Storage::url() in Digital Ocean spaces too slow

Tags: laravel, filesystems, storage, digital-ocean

For Laravel 9, I'm using Digital Ocean spaces and `Storage::url()` to return the full bucket endpoint for files.
I've been facing latency issues and I realized that problem was related to ApiResource returning this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'url' => Storage::url('files/'.$this->filename),
        'thumb_lg' => Storage::url('files/thumbs-lg/'.$this->filename),
        'thumb_md' => Storage::url('files/thumbs-md/'.$this->filename),
        'thumb_sm' => Storage::url('files/thumbs-sm/'.$this->filename),
        'width' => $this->width,
        'height' => $this->height
    ];
}
```

As soon I remove `Storage::url()` latency is decreased about 400ms in my endpoint.
I'm wondering if there is a way to improve this. I want to avoid writing the URL manually but the time is not acceptable at all.
As I understand, this method hits the storage to get the domain.

Any advice will be appreciated.